# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 8

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication, syntax

I' am tryin to make a registration and login system for my website and I am getting the parse error:`syntax error unexpected 'else'(T_ELSE)` in the login file when I click on login what could be the problem?
Below is the file with the code:

```
    <?php
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
}
}
else
{

echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}   

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login';
```

Comment: added an extra closing brace } after if..

Answer (score 3):

Two curly brackets are closed `}` after `header('Location: index.php');`. Make it one and try.

Comment: okay thanks i have fixed the extra brackets but I am still getting an error when I hit the login button to the site and I am getting "Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6 Fatal error: Call to a member function is_logged_in() on null in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6" in the same file and I dont know where I am going wrong as I am also a begginner in php and I would like my login system to work

Answer (score 3):

remove `}` after else :

```
if($user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
} else {
    echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra curly brace.

Change

```
//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); 

}
  }
```

To

```
//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); 

}
```

Comment: okay thanks i have fixed the extra brackets but I am still getting an error when I hit the login button to the site and I am getting "Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6 Fatal error: Call to a member function is_logged_in() on null in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6" in the same file and I dont know where I am going wrong as I am also a begginner in php and I would like my login system to work

Answer (score 0):

You have a double closed bracket before your first else statement; take one out:

```
if($user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); 

 }
   //} <- this is the extra one that shouldnt be there
  else
{
```

Answer (score 0):

this is correct code, u Two curly brackets are closed **}**

```
//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); 

  }
  else
  {

echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}**strong text**   

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login';
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your code well, you had double curly brackets in your code.

```
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){

    header('Location: index.php');

} else {

      echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
  }   

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added extra } in if loop. Please replace below code.

```
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){ 
   header('Location: index.php'); 
}
else
{
   echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing bracket here:

```
if($user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: index.php'); 

}
  }
....
```

This should be like:

```
if($user->is_logged_in())
{ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
}
else
{
    echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}
```

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to always use proper formatting this will help you to find out these kind of issues.

Comment: okay thanks i have fixed the extra brackets but I am still getting an error when I  hit the login button to the site and I am getting "Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function is_logged_in() on null in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6" in the same file and I dont know where I am going wrong as I am also a begginner in php and I would like my login system to work

Comment: @gugie1: for ist issue, u dont have $user variable in your code.. for second maybe this function is not avaialbe  is_logged_in(), , please show me full code.

Comment: @gugie1: just tell me, where u define is_logged_in() function ??? in which file>